# Converting for loop output to string

Tags: python

How would I convert the output of this loop to a string in this format?

ABCDEF,BCDEFG,CDEFGH,DEFGHI

```
fileHandle = open( 'urls.txt', 'r' )
raw_URLS = fileHandle.readlines()

for items in raw_URLS:
    print(items[26:32])

fileHandle.close()
```

urls.txt:

```
www.example.com/directory/ABCDEF/pagename
www.example.com/directory/BCDEFG/pagename
www.example.com/directory/CDEFGH/pagename
www.example.com/directory/DEFGHI/pagename
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.join` in a list comprehension:

```
data = ','.join([item[26:32] for item in open( 'urls.txt', 'r' )])
```

Comment: `items[26:32]` already seems to be the desired part of each URL. Why do you need a regex then in addition?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I added a solution to account for that.

Comment: Yes that *is* the solution. Just leave the first part away, it only distracts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable to store string before the loop, and then iterate over the loop concatenating the string.

Your code would look like something like this:

```
string_you_want = ''
fileHandle = open( 'urls.txt', 'r' )
raw_URLS = fileHandle.readlines()

for items in raw_URLS:
    string_you_want = string_you_want + items[26:32] + ','
    print(items[26:32])

fileHandle.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
f=open("urls.txt")
for line in f:
    print (line[26:32])
```

Answer (score 0):

If your url pattern is same then try:

```
import re
result=[]
pattern=r'[A-Z]+'
with open('new_file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(pattern,line):
            result.append(re.search(pattern,line).group())

print(result)
```

output:

```
['ABCDEF', 'BCDEFG', 'CDEFGH', 'DEFGHI']
```